# Limits in Double Integration Question

Tags: integration, integral-transforms

I’m really having problems getting suitable limits when using double integration. For example:

Let $E$ be a region defined by

$$E=\left\{(x,y): y-x \leq 2,\ x + y \geq 4,\ 2x + y \leq 8\right\}$$

Sketch the region $E$.

The sketching is never a problem. So for this one we have:

$y = 8-2x$, $y=x+2$ and $y=4-x$ - the triangle between all the lines is the region $E$.

Find the area of $E$ and calculate

$$\int\!\!\!\int_{E}\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d} x\, \mathrm{d} y$$

The integration isn’t the problem. I’m really confused as to how to get the correct limits. Our notes say to fix a variable and then look at the boundary of the other. So if we fix $x\in (1,4)$ then taking $y=x+2$ and $y=8-2x$ will give me a greater area then needed....

I hope someone can explain this to me as I’m rather confused!

Comment: @user4645: You've been ignoring my comments here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41230/limits-in-double-integration and here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41670/riemann-stieltjes-integral. Please show more respect for the site. If you go on like this I may start flagging your questions.

Comment: @joriki:  I posted an answer before I saw your comment. I think your comment is a good one, so deleted the answer.  Let me think if you think I should repost.

Comment: @Ross: Thanks. My tendency would be to wait with reposting until user4645 has made some effort to cooperate.

Comment: @user4645: Find the corners of the triangle. I get $(1,3)$, $(3,5)$, and $(4,0)$. We have to decide whether to integrate first w.r.t. $x$ or w.r.t. $y$. Doing $x$ first sounds hard, you will get logs, which you need to later integrate.  So try to integrate first w.r.t. $y$.  The "top" boundary changes.  So break up the region using a vertical line through $(3,5)$.  In the left region, $y$ goes from $4-x$ to $x+2$. Integrate (trivial). Then integrate w.r.t. $x$, from $1$ to $3$. Please leave a message if the process is not clear.

Comment: hi... ive corrected my mistakes. sorry about that!

Comment: can someone post a pic of the breakdown and explain how you get the boundaries/limits? its really confusing me!