# Determine limits in double integration

Tags: integration

I've tried to search the site but haven't really found a satisfactory answer. Not one that I understood anyways. Specifically, I looked at this: [Limits in Double Integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41230/limits-in-double-integration) and [Limits in Double Integration Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/41675/limits-in-double-integration-question).

I am given the following function and asked to find the value of $k$ that makes this into a valid joint probability density function:

$ f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 
      k & 0 \leq x \leq 2\,,\quad 0 \leq y \leq 1\,,\quad 2y \leq x \\[1mm]
      0 & \mbox{otherwise}
   \end{cases}
$

Obviously, I need to setup and solve something like this:

$
\int_{a}^{b}\int_{c}^{d} k d? d? = 1
$

I'm having a terrible time understanding how to determine the limits of integration here, to the point that I'm not even sure if I should integrate over $x$ or $y$ first.

I know that homework questions aren't appreciated (and this is a homework question), but I've been struggling with this question for over an hour and I'm not closer to understanding now than I was when I started.

Comment: Excuse me, but does it even matter?  Integrating a constant $k$ comes out the same regardless of which variable you integrate with respect to.  Perhaps you meant to put $f(x,y)$ inside?

Comment: I'm trying to understand how to setup the limits of integration here, given the limitations on the function. What if, instead of a constant the integrand was, I don't know... $xy$. How do I factor in the statement $2y \leq x$?

Comment: I would just find the area of the region (graphical integration).

Comment: I want to understand how to setup the limits of integration here. When I'm going to be asked this question in an exam I'll only have only a pen and paper, and the function may be considerably more complex, making graphical integration impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The region

$$ \{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:0\leq x \leq 2, 0 \leq y \leq 1, 2y \leq x\}$$

is a triangle in $\mathbb R^2$ (maybe it will be helpful for you to draw it). To integrate in this region you can do it two ways. You should think of it as describing this region one variable at a time.

**First $x$ then $y$:**

Given $y$, the region includes all $x$'s that satisfy $2y \leq x \leq 2$. And it includes all $y$'s such that $0 \leq y \leq 1$. This leads to the integral

$$ \int_0^1\int_{2y}^2 k\;dxdy .$$

**First $y$ then $x$:**

Given $x$, the region includes all $y$'s that satisfy $0 \leq y \leq x/2$. And it includes all $x$'s such that $0 \leq x \leq 2$. This leads to the integral

$$ \int_0^2\int_0^{x/2} k\;dydx .$$

Comment: Thank you so much. You answered while I typing out my best guess at an answer. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I don't know if this is right, but it's the best I have. If there's a mistake, kindly point it out:

From $2y \leq x$ we determine that $y \leq \frac{x}{2}$. We set up our double integral thusly:

\[
\int_{x=0}^{x=2}\int_{y=0}^{y=\frac{x}{2}}kdydx \Rightarrow k\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{x}{2}}dydx
\]

Let's do the inner integral first:
\[
\int_{0}^{\frac{x}{2}}dy = y\bigg|_{0}^{\frac{x}{2}} = \frac{x}{2} - 0 = \frac{x}{2}
\]

Now, we'll use this to evaluate the outer integral:

\[
k\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{x}{2}}dydx = k\int_{0}^{2}\frac{x}{2}dx = \frac{k}{2}\int_{0}^{2}xdx = \frac{k}{2}\Bigg[\frac{x^2}{2}\Bigg]_{0}^{2} = \frac{k}{2}\Big(\frac{2^2}{2} - 0\Big) = k
\]

Since we are seeking to make this a valid joint probability density function, we conclude that $k = 1$.